# Large memory usage slows down unrelated code

Tags: performance, go, memory

I am maintaing the code for a Go project that reads and writes a lot of data and that has done so successfully for some time. Recently, I made a change: a CSV file with about 2 million records is loaded in a map with struct values at the beginning of the program. This map is only used in part B, but first part A is executed. And this first part already runs noticeably slower than before (processing time is quadrupled). That is very strange since that part of the logic did not change.
I have spent a week trying to explain how this can happen. Here are the steps I have taken (when I mention performance, I always refer to part A, which does not include the time to load the data in memory and actually has nothing to do with it):

- The program was running on a server inside a Docker container. But I have been able to reproduce it on my laptop without container: the performance indeed decreases compared to when I run it without the data from the file loaded in memory.
- The server had a huge amount of RAM. Although obviously more memory is used when the file is loaded, no limits are hit. I also did not see spikes or other strange patterns in memory usage and disk I/O. For these checks, I have used pprof, htop and iotop.
- When the data is loaded but then the map set to nil, performance is OK again.
- Loading the data in a slice instead of a map reduces the performance decrease from x4 to x2 (but the memory usage is more or less the same as with the map).
- This made me wonder whether the map/slice is accessed somewhere in part A, even though it shouldn’t. The map is stored in a field of a struct type. I checked and this struct is always passed by pointer (including all goroutines). Making it a global variable instead of a pointer field did not solve the issue.
- There is one dependency outside of the standard library. Is the problem caused by the library? It forces some garbage collects. Disabling this does not make a difference. I found another similar library that is unrelated and using this one as a replacement improves performance, but it still takes longer when the data of the file is loaded.

Here I have plotted the metrics with and without the data in memory: [image]

What could cause this effect or how do I find it out?

Comment: Can you please add labels to X & Y axis on the graph

Comment: Two comments.  First, what specifically is your question?  Do you want to know how to trace a memory leak?  Second, you haven't shown a minimal example or indeed any code.  So it's difficult to guess what is going on

Comment: "`The server had a huge amount of RAM. Although obviously more memory is used when the file is loaded, no limits are hit`". How about CPU cache size limit? E.g. maybe loading the data causes all other data to get pushed out of the cache (and makes code using the other data slower due to cache misses).

Comment: Updated the question with labels on the axes and an explicit question.

Comment: @Brendan Interesting, that is something I had not thought of. But I do not believe that is what I am running into. The part of the code that is running more slowly consists of file reading and writing, without any previous data involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I get this right, your flow looks something like this:

1. Read 2 million rows from CSV into map -> struct
2. Run part A (which doesn't need data from CSV)
3. Run part B, using data from CSV

Why read the data before you need it, would be the first question, but that's perhaps besides the point.

What is likely is that 2 million structs in a map are routinely being accessed by the garbage collector, actually. Depending on what value `GOGC` has, the pacer component of the garbage collector is likely to kick in more often as the amount of memory allocated increases. Because this map is set aside for later use, there's nothing for the GC to do, but it's taking up cycles in checking the data regardless. There's a number of things you could do to verify, and account for this behaviour - all of these things should can help you rule out/confirm whether or not garbage collection is slowing you down.

- Profile the code (obviously, important for diagnostics) IIRC, the CPU profile shows GC interventions more readily
- Try disabling garbage collection (`debug.SetGCPercent(-1)`)
- Store the map in a `sync.Pool`. This is a type designed for you to keep stuff you'll manage manually, and move outside of regular GC cycles.
- Only read the CSV when you need to, don't read it before *"part A"*
- Stream the file, instead of reading it in a massive map. 2 million rows, what's the value of reading all of this in memory, rather than reading line by line?

Comment: Why read the data before I need it: to fail (or warn) fast if it is not of the expected format.

Comment: I read the 2 million records in memory because they are not in the order I need them to be. The way I circumvented the problem up to now was by reading the records, sorting them and writing them again (using gob). They can then be removed from memory and streamed.

Comment: Disabling garbage collection indeed solved the performance degradation. Would the `sync.Pool` be the preferred solution for a production environment? I have a lot of data that needs to be kept in memory throughout the whole run.

Comment: @Socci: I don't have enough information to tell you whether or not `sync.Pool` is the best solution here. Getting something from the pool requires runtime type assertions, so you may end up wrapping the data into a type, and assert it to an interface, so you only need to do that once, so yeah, that could be a solution. I'd try and tweak the `GOGC` value, too, and compare